# Возможно ли стилизовать картинку загруженную через свойства content в css

Tags: css

Slick slider использую для сайта.

У него есть свои базовые кнопки *изменить слайд влево или вправо* вот стили для кнопки

```
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    font: normal normal normal 22px/0 FontAwesome;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

я загрузил свою картинку в **CSS** используя `content` но не могу его стилизовать.

Возможно ли стилизовать картинку который я загружаю через content в css?

Вот тут

```
.slick-prev:before {
    content: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-line-1/100/v_arrow_left-right-512.png");
}
```

Хочу отменить эти кнопки и положить свои картину вместо скучных кнопок

```js
/*Slider function [It is recommended to place a function in a separate JS file, such as "functions.js"]*/
function myCoolSlider() {
        $('#featured-content').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    }
    /*End of Slider function*/



$(document).ready(function() {

  
/*Calling the function [It is recommended to call a function in a separate JS file, such as "scripts.js"]*/
    myCoolSlider();
/*.................End of call*/


});
```

```css
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    font: normal normal normal 22px/0 FontAwesome;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.slick-prev {
    left: 0;
}
.slick-prev:before {
    content: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-line-1/100/v_arrow_left-right-512.png");
}
.slick-next {
    right: 0;
}
.slick-next:before {
    content: '>'
}
/* Slick slider: Content */

.slick-slide a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slick-slide h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: -7%;
}

/* Dots */

.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '•';
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .25;
    color: black;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}

/* main -  */

.slider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

figure {
    cursor: auto;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em 20px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
.slick-next {
    right: -60px;
}
.slick-slide img {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.css"/>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick-theme.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>

        
       
        <div class="slider" id="featured-content">
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9">
          <img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168">
              </figure>
               <h2>[#1]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming history of the past 25 years</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>Best game reboots</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#3]The greatest breakthroughs</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#4]The greatest breakthroughs</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#5]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#6]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming history of</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#7]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming history of the past</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#8]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming history of the past 25 years</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a href="#">
               <figure class="thumbnail ratio-16by9"><img class="our-work-empty-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/168x168"></figure>
               <h2>[#9]The greatest breakthroughs in gaming history of the past 25 years</h2>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Куча кода и непонятный вопрос...

Comment: @Air щас добавлья пояснения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.slick-prev {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff url('arrow-left.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

button.slick-next {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff url('arrow-right.png') 100% 100% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

С позиционированием и изменением картинки думаю разберётесь, размеры указаны чтобы сработало `background: 100% 100%`, возможно есть более элегантное решение.

Увидел что надо через `content` а тут вот возник затык.

Comment: спасибо щас проверью и приму ответ.А какое более элегантное решение по вашему мнению?

Comment: ну в моём решении вышло что используются 2 картинки, не очень разбираюсь в спрайтах поэтому через спрайты будет элегантнее

Comment: Немного поправил код, посмотрите. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLNqqd?editors=0100

Comment: спасибо сработало